# Proper HTTP Client method

Tags: java, android, http

I'm trying to run a method that I created, but it won't run more than once. I think my problem is that I'm never releasing the connection.

I tried to follow this tutorial but some of the methods don't work and I don't know why.
http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html

```
public String sendMessage(String username, Editable message){

        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;
        try{


            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI("http://abc.com/user_send.php?username="+username+"&message="+message);

            HttpPost post_request = new HttpPost();
            post_request.setURI(website);


            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

            request.setURI(website);
            //executing actual request
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(l);

            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return "ERROR";
        }

        }
```

Comment: How do you call sendMessage() method first time and second time?

Comment: The method is called onClick of a "send" button on my layout.

Comment: What exactly happens? ERROR is printed for second time? By "method" you mean sendMessage(String username, Editable message) or the http post method?

Comment: I figured out my problem lies somewhere when I handle my response. When I call this method, I check if the response equals "0" and if it does to toast "Success" and to clear the message from the UI.

Comment: Great, glad to hear you found the problem. Maybe you should answer your own question, so other people do not think you still need help ;) Good luck with the rest of the project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do you know that the `post_request` never get used? Only the GET method (`request`) is send to the server.

Anyway, here is my code which exactly copies yours (only Editable is String in my case) and should be compilable and runnable as is. For me it works. Every time I click the button the GET `request` is performed.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  /** Creates new form NewJFrame */
  public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
  }


  public String sendMessage(String username, String message){

    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    try{


        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://abc.com/user_send.php?username="+username+"&message="+message);

        //!!!this is never used
        HttpPost post_request = new HttpPost();
        post_request.setURI(website);


        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

        request.setURI(website);
        //executing actual request
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(l);

        }
        in.close();

        data = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("Success:\n" + data);


        return data;
    }catch (Exception e){
        return "ERROR";
    }

  }


  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(64, 64, 64)
            .add(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(239, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .add(58, 58, 58)
            .add(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(213, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
  }// </editor-fold>

  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    sendMessage("ondra", "textX");
  }

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
  }

  private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;

}
```